# Reporters for Flutter integration testing

Tags: flutter, testrail, jira-xray, flutter-integration-test, jfrog-xray

I am looking for examples of integrations among Flutter Integration library and test management tools like TestRail or Xray.
For Cypress and other browser automation tools I can find plenty of solutions but for Flutter integration basically nothing.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, can I kindly ask you to mark as correct? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xray, there's no tutorial yet. However, it should be fairly simple.

Run your tests using `flutter test` and pass the  `--machine` argument to generate a JSON report.
Use the [junitreport package](https://pub.dev/packages/junitreport) to generate a JUnit XML report.
Then you can add it to your command as such:

`flutter test --machine | tojunit -o junit.xml`

If you redirect this to a file,  then you have the report that you can submit to Xray for example.
For Xray server/datacenter, you need to call [the REST API endpoint](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-JUnitXMLresults), something like:

`curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u username:password -F "file=@junit.xml" http://yourserver/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/junit?projectKey=JIRAPROJECTKEY`

For [Xray on Jira Cloud,](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-JUnitXMLresults) the syntax is slightly different. You have to make an [authentication request](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Authentication+-+REST+v2) first, and then do another submiting the JUnit XML report.

```
token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{ "client_id": "32A27E69B0AC4E5000000...","client_secret": "d62f81eb9ed859e1....." }'  https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate)
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"junit.xml" https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution/junit?projectKey=XTP
```

Answer (score 0):

For Report in flutter integration testing you can use 3rd party tools like **TESTRAIL**.

> I created Package to easily integrate TESTRAIL in flutter:
> [flutter_testrail](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_testrail)
>
> For E.g Check this [Flutter_TestRail Example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_testrail/example)

Now once you created your TestRail Account then configure in our test setup:

```
    TestRail.configure(
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      /// The url that points to the test rail server => https://example.testrail.com
      serverDomain: 'https://YOUR_SERVER.testrail.com',
    )
```

> Define your initial test status in test file:

```
 TestStatus testStatusResults= TestStatus(
          caseId: 1758,
          statusId: 3,
          comment: 'Verify that user is able to see the splash screen',
        ),
```

> And then update your test status on TESTRAIL:

```
  /// Equivalent Status Code:
  /// 1: Passed
  /// 2: Blocked
  /// 3: Untested (not allowed when adding a new result)
  /// 4: Retest
  /// 5: Failed
  ///
  ///  So Pass Status Code according to your test status
  static Future<void> reportMultipleTestCaseResults(
    List<TestStatus> testStatusResults,
  ) async {
    final testRun = await TestRun.get(3); //replace 3 with your own Run Id.
    await testRun.addResultsForCases(
      testStatusResults,
    );
  }
```